# Using ROOT (cern) with mingw32

Tags: mingw32, root-framework

Can I install Cern's ROOT on win32 without MSVS but with mingw32? I want to develop some C/C++ programs, which will use ROOT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, compiling with mingw32 is [currently not supported](http://root.cern.ch/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=10652). I guess it would technically be possible, as mingw32 is based on gcc, but it would be a lot of work.

The best way seems to be to use MSVC++ (even the free express version will do). [ROOT builder](http://rootbuilder.codeplex.com/) is a nice tool that uses mingw32 (but the MS compiler) and builds ROOT for you, without the need for the command line.

Another option would be to use cygwin, but that is also unsupported, and it's probably slower, because it introduces a layer of indirection to convert posix calls to windows.

Here are some links to further information:

http://www.muenster.de/~naumana/root.html

http://root.cern.ch/root/HowtoWindows.html